# Animate Automatic Resize of Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, animation

In HTML, I have a `form`, wrapped in a `div`. This `div` does not have an explicit `height` set in CSS, but instead chances `height` depending on the contents.

When a user presses a button, a Javascript function adds several elements to the form. Again, no explicit `height` is dealt with; the `div` just resizes to fit its new contents.

When a user presses another button, a Javascript function removes the first element from the form.

Is there any way to smoothly animate these adjustments, using Javascript? The project currently uses jQuery, so anything built into that is available.

**Demo Code:**

```
<!--HTML FILE-->
<!--...-->
<button onclick="add_field();">ADD FIELD</button>
<button onclick="del_field();">DEL FIELD</button>
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="text_field"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
<!--...--->
```

```
//Javascript File
function add_field()
{
    $("<input type='text'/>").insertBefore($("#text_field"));
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("<input type='text'/>")
    .css('display', 'none')
    .insertBefore($("#text_field"))
    .toggle(_duration);
```

Comment: This does indeed resize the `div` on adds, but how about removes?

Comment: @pcperini very similar. just use call back. like, 
`$('#text_field').toggle(_duration, function() { $(this).remove(); });`. and don't forget to check this answer if it does help you :)